# The 2-point correlation matrix $C_{ij}$ fully characterises a free eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$, what characterises a superposition of eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information

Consider a system of free fermions with Hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_{ij} t_{ij}c^{\dagger}_ic_j\quad \longrightarrow \quad H = \sum_k E_k d^{\dagger}_kd_k.
$$
An eigenstate  $|\psi \rangle$ of $H$ is given by acting on $|0\rangle$ with $d^{\dagger}$s as usual:
$$
|\psi^{N_p}\rangle = \prod_{a \in N_p} d_a | 0 \rangle \quad \text{where} \quad d_a = \sum_i\phi^a_ic_i,
$$
for some suitable $\phi$s. As shown by Sun Woo Kim in my [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/630762/), any eigenstate is fully characterised (all its correlators can be obtained) from the 2-point correlator matrix $C$ given by
$$
C_{ij} = \langle \psi | c^{\dagger}_i c_j |\psi\rangle \equiv \langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j \rangle_{\psi}.
$$
If I have a superposition of eigenstates,
$$
|\xi\rangle =\sum_n a_n |\psi_n\rangle,
$$
**does it also have a 2-point correlator that fully characterises $|\xi\rangle $?**

I am inclined to think not because if I try the brute force approach
$$
C_{ij}\doteq \sum_na_n\sum_{k}\overline{\phi^k_i}\phi^k_j\langle d^{\dagger}_k d_k \rangle_{\psi_n}=\sum_n a_n \langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j \rangle_{\psi_n}
$$
then
$$
\langle multi \rangle = \sum_n a_n \sum_{\mathcal{i,j,.. \in P}} \langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j\rangle_{\psi_n}\cdots = \sum_{\mathcal{i,j,.. \in P}} \sum_n a_n \langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j\rangle_{\psi_n}\cdots \neq  \sum_{\mathcal{i,j,.. \in P}} C_{ij}\cdots
$$
as I would need extra $a_n$'s to absorb them into $C_{ij}$'s.

(This is perhaps also related to my previous question of whether or not a sum of gaussian matrices is gaussian)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - coherent states form an (overcomplete) basis for the (infinite-dimensional) Hilbert space, and otherwise, *any* state could be characterized by its second moments.

More generally, there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between physically admissible 2-point correlation matrices and Gaussian states. Thus, for any non-Gaussian state which can be characterized from its 2-point corrlations, the way in which this is done must be different from what it is for Gaussian states (i.e., Wick's theorem). (Of course, for any *given* state there is such a relation - the simplest one being "Ignore the 2-point correlations, this is the state.")

Comment: As always, thank you very much for all your help! I guess I will have to explore other routes...

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Well, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As you probably know, there is a very effective way of calculating the  entanglement negativity of a Gaussian state. But judging from my questions and your answers the state I'm interested in is not gaussian... Tbf that's the only feasable route of computing the negativity of a state that I know.

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Why don't you ask what you actually want to know? I.e.: I have the state X and want to know its entanglement negativity?

Comment: Apologies, you are right, I didn't because I don't believe it has been done before so I assumed that asking the question directly was pointless so I just asked the missing bits of own my ongoing calculation based on close things in the literature (which turned out to be a dead end, of course..). I might ask the question in a new post.

Answer (score 1):

You only get everything form the two point correlator when the  wavefunction can be written as a *single* Slater determinant, or equivalently as a *single* tensor product of one-particle states. The general state is a sum of many tensor product states.

The conditions that an $n$-fermion  state can be written a single tensor product  are  the [Plucker relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding).

Comment: So are you saying that if one can find some new fermionic operators whose particle states reproduce $|\xi\rangle$ then the state is Gaussian?